# Change of basis. Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have:

- A basis $B = \{(1,2,2,1),(2,-1,1 ,1)\}$;
- A vector of coordinates with respect to $B$, $w = (7,4,8,5)$;
- The change of basis matrix $P$ from $B$ to $Y$, $M_B^Y = \Big[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 \end{smallmatrix}\Big]$

We are now going to determine the basis $Y$ and the vector $w$ with respect to $Y$.

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, the columns of $M_B^Y$ should give you the basis vectors of $Y$ in terms of the basis $w$. But, that matrix is the wrong size: if you have 4D space, a basis has to have four vectors, and a change of basis matrix must be $4\times4$, not $2\times2$. So please, give us a usable matrix.

Comment: Also, $B$ cannot be a basis, since the vectors must belong to 4D space $\mathbb{R}^4$, whereas they are only two. And $w$ is decidedly not expressed in terms of $B$, because $w$ has 4 coordinates, and $B$ has only two vectors. So complete the basis, fix the change of basis matrix, and then we might be able to answer.

Comment: Your question is confused. $B$ is the basis of a _subspace_ of $\Bbb R^4$ that happens to contain $w$, but not of the whole space; calling $B$ a basis without mentioning that subspace makes little sense.

Comment: If $B$ is supposed to be a basis of a subspace, still $w$ cannot be of coordinates with respect to $B$ but a vector in the span of $B$ expressed in some coordinates, presumably canonical coordinates.

Comment: $w$ represented with $B$ would be $(3,2)$, as Marc wrote in his answer below, and the rest of the question is fully answered by that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call those vectors of $B$ respectively $b_1$ and $b_2$. They are independent, and span a subspace $W$ of $\Bbb R^4$ of dimension $2$. So $B$ is a basis of $W$. That subspace contains $w$, since $w=3b_1+2b_2$. Now presumably $Y$ is another basis of $W$, and I suppose $P=M_B^Y = \bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ means that $Y=[y_1,y_2]$ with $y_1=b_1+4b_2$ and $y_2=2b_1+3b_2$ (that is, I suppose the columns of the matrix give the coordinates of each $y_j$ with respect to the basis $B$ of $W$; depending on convention, it could alternatively be that the change of basis matrix gives coordinates of each $b_j$ with respect to the basis $Y$ of $W$, but I won't assume that).

Now you can directly determine what the $y_j$ are from the above expressions. You can also find the coefficients $(p,q)$ such that $w=py_1+qy_2$, even without using the explicit values of the vectors $y_1,y_2$, just by solving $P\cdot\binom pq=\binom32$, since $py_1+qy_2=(p+2q)b_1+(4p+3q)b_2$, and you need that to be equal to $2b_1+3b_2$. Those $(p,q)$ are the coordinates of $w$ with respect to $Y$ (I find $(p,q)=(-1,2)$).